# Get characters which are not in brackets REGEX

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-recursion

I'm basically working on custom query building. I've designed the pattern as field_set and sub_field_sets. A sample Query:

```
({e:3}.{f:44}.{f:2}) + ( 
                   ({e:3}.{f:44}.{f:3}) + ({e:3}.{f:44}.{f:4}) 
                        ) - ({e:3}.{f:44}.{f:5})
```

I want to get all operators from root using REGEX. Which in this case should result  ['+', '-'] and **NOT** ['+', '+', '-']

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking. You need to provide more examples, give us the list of possible operators, etc. From what you posted, using `strpos($query, $operator) !== false` for each operator should work, at least...

Answer (score 0):

This works on given sample:

```
([+-])(?![^+)-]+\)\s*\))
```

Comment: You can shorten your regex a bit with removing the escapes for `+` and `-` in character classes. They are not required if these are only characters in the character class.

Comment: You missed slash in `[^+\-)]` for even one more byte saved :P Just move `-` as last character in character class :P